# Detect unmanaged memory leak in a managed application

Tags: c#, c++, memory-leaks

I'm working on a project which the main application is written in C# and some of the infrastructure is in C++.
I've just found that I have unmanaged memory leaks which I try to trace down.
I've been marking code in and out for days already but was able to find only some of the leaks.

All leak detectors apps (purify, leak detector, etc') work only on unmanaged applications (while mine is in C#).

Any idea of good memory leak detectors for such cases? any other ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you know your memory leak is in your unmanaged code then could you not create a test app in unmanaged code or even a test harness/unit test and use a profiler on that?

Comment: I wish I could, there is a long chain of mixed code which is hard to break. The initiation of the chain must be done from a managed code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried ANTS memory profiler? Worked well for me.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/?utm_source=simpletalk&utm_medium=article&utm_content=mikebloise&utm_campaign=antsmemoryprofiler

Comment: Thanks for replying but I think it works only on managed code, no?

Comment: I think that ANTS does not support unmanaged code. You want something that supports both managed and unmanaged code? If so, you should maybe try with GlowCode it suports mixed applications